# Laggy UI with 2 GPUs

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, arch-linux, nvidia-graphics-card, amd-radeon

I have 2 GPUs:

1. AMD RX 580 (Main GPU)
2. NVIDIA GTX 750 Ti

I have two monitors and a TV connected to my Main GPU, and another third monitor connected to my NVIDIA GPU, because it has a DVI +4 Output. But the Problem is, that the Display is really laggy, like 40 to 50 Hz, although it shows that it's running at 60 Hz...
I am using only Open Source Drivers in my Arch Linux system for both the GPUs, because i'm on KDE Plasma under Wayland, and the NVIDIA Proprietary Drivers suck for that.

I'm using an MSI B450 Gaming Pro Carbon Max WIFI Mainboard with a small Ryzen 3 1200 (which I actually regret bying). My PCI Connections have the following configuration:

1. AMD RX 580 (16x Slot)
2. Empty Slot (1x Slot)
3. USB 3.0 Card (1x Slot)
4. NVIDIA GTX 750 Ti (4x Slot)
5. Empty Slot (1x Slot)

If I open a GPU-heavy Program with the variable "DRI_PRIME=1", the Monitor connected to my NVIDIA GPU will be even laggier, but also strangely the Monitor in which the Application is running is also very Laggy.

It seems as if the AMD GPU is rendering everything and then sending the output to my NVIDIA card, which just outputs the data to my Monitor. Is this correct?

I don't know how to diagnose the problem, there show no errors in the systemd logs. I'll give you every Information needed tho.

Thanks for your Help!

Comment: The "rendering on one card and sending to the other" is definitely my experience on Windows as well. I know windows has a tool where you can choose which GPU is used to do work for particular apps and that definitely changes the behaviour. Seems something might work on arch: https://superuser.com/questions/1300860/use-specific-graphics-card-for-a-task-on-arch-linux but you've already tried one of those solutions

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1244495/set-display-to-use-intel-graphics-but-use-nvidia-gpu-for-application-rendering suggests "bumblebee" and "bbswitch" as potential tools.

Comment: The Problem with that is, that bumblebee is only for the proprietary NVIDIA Driver, and bbswitch is only for Optimus Laptops...

Comment: Fair enough, I had hoped that they would be more generic.

Comment: Yeah, would be super nice if a program existed that would do that.

Comment: Since you are using Wayland I believe the Wayland Compositor is responsible for this (that would be KWin). It can't force applications to run on a certain GPU, but its job involves taking the frames from the Radeon and shuttle them to the GTX, which it should be able to do, 60 times a second with only a very slight lag. It might need special configuration for this kind of arrangement.

Comment: Seems to be some more hints to force applications to particular GPUs at https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/wn13gw/how_to_select_specific_gpu_with_prime_on_wayland/

Comment: The Problem is not, that I can't force a Program to run on another GPU. DRI_PRIME=1 works every time for me. The problem is the lagginess tho. Isn't there some way to enable compression between the GPUs in KWin?

Comment: Compression shouldn't be an issue unless you have a particularly slow connection between the two GPUs. A PCIe 3 x16 connection should have somewhere close to 16GB/s of bandwidth. Even your x4 connection should be ~4GB/s, unless that slot is only PCIe 2.0 which would limit you to around 1.5 GB/s of usable bandwidth. A 4K screen at 32-bits deep running at 60fps (3840 x 2160 x 4 x 60) should be approximately 1.8GB/s (1990656000 bytes/s).  PCIe does not support compression over the link.

Comment: Ok then that shouldn't be the issue... My Monitor connected to the NVIDIA Card runs at 1440x900 at 60 Hz... What else could be the bottleneck?

Comment: How do you know it is 40-50 Hz and that 40-50 Hz is really laggy?

Comment: It's so bad that you can literally notice it with your eyes.